# How to compare Rectangle<T, U> for shape equality?

Tags: rust

Given

```
struct Rectangle<T, U> {
    x: T,
    y: U,
}

let first = Rectangle { x: 3.2, y: 1 };
let second = Rectangle { x: 1, y: 3.2 };
let third = Rectangle { x: 3, y: 1 };
```

how do I declare/implement a safe `fn same_shape_as(&self, …) -> bool` which returns true for `first, first`, `first, second` and `second, first`, but false for `first, third`? (Not necessarily looking for a full implementation, but just which syntax/concepts are involved.) For example, is there some way to `match` on the types of properties being equal, or to check whether two values are comparable before attempting to compare them?

To clarify, a naive Python (yes, I'm aware of duck typing) implementation might be the following:

```
def same_shape_as(self, other):
    if type(self.x) == type(other.x) and type(self.y) == type(other.y):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
    elif type(self.x) == type(other.y) and type(self.y) == type(other.x):
        return self.x == other.y and self.y == other.x
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you've asked for `first, second` to be true ... but they don't match anyway? I imagine thats a typo or are you asking something else?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead The idea is that {x, y} in the first matches {y, x} in the second, and for my purposes that makes their shape equal.

Comment: Why not give `x` and `y` the same type? It will make things much easier.

Comment: @EvilTak I'm trying to learn Rust, and trying to mix up the examples in the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-01-syntax.html) to internalize properly.

Comment: I see where you are coming from. TBH, that is a terrible example for using two different generic type parameters, since an integer can very well be encapsulated in a float. You would (should) never get a situation like this in actual production code.

Comment: Sure. I figured the example in the book was even less realistic: Write a `mixup` function which takes two `Point`s and returns a `Point` with one value from one and another from the other. Like most programming introductions, it gets harder and harder to find realistic examples the further in you get. It would be awesome if someone could find a reasonable example to deal with two variables of the same struct but different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to somewhat mimic dynamically typed language by using `Any`

```
fn compare<T, U, V, W>(a: &Rect<T, U>, b: &Rect<V, W>) -> bool
where 
    T: Any + PartialEq + 'static, U: Any + PartialEq + 'static,
    V: Any + 'static, W: Any + 'static,
{
    if Any::is::<T>(&b.x) && Any::is::<U>(&b.y) {
        Some(&a.x) == Any::downcast_ref::<T>(&b.x) &&
        Some(&a.y) == Any::downcast_ref::<U>(&b.y) 
    } else if Any::is::<T>(&b.y) && Any::is::<U>(&b.x) {
        Some(&a.x) == Any::downcast_ref::<T>(&b.y) &&
        Some(&a.y) == Any::downcast_ref::<U>(&b.x) 
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

I would go by implementing `PartialEq` and a simple helper function which swaps the elements of a structure.

```
struct Rect<T, U> {
    x: T,
    y: U,
}

impl<T, U> Rect<T, U> {
    // Reverse the order of structure fields
    // References allow the use of non-copiable types T and U
    fn rev(&self) -> Rect<&U, &T> {
        Rect {
            x: &self.y,
            y: &self.x,
        }
    }
}

impl<T, U> PartialEq for Rect<T, U>
where
    T: PartialEq,
    U: PartialEq,
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.x == other.x && self.y == other.y
    }
}

// Allows to compare Rect<T, U> and Rect<&T, &U>
impl<'a, T, U> PartialEq<Rect<&'a T, &'a U>> for Rect<T, U>
where
    T: PartialEq,
    U: PartialEq,
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &Rect<&'a T, &'a U>) -> bool {
        &self.x == other.x && &self.y == other.y
    }
}

fn main() {
    let first = Rect { x: 3.2, y: 1 };
    let second = Rect { x: 1, y: 3.2 };
    let third = Rect { x: 3, y: 1 };
    let fourth = Rect { x: 3.1, y: 2 };


    assert_eq!(first == second.rev(), true);
    assert_eq!(first == fourth, false);
    // assert_eq!(first == third, false); // Compilation error
    assert_eq!(first == first, true);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=af36a188abb96e27a0bb45e20996d0af&version=stable)

Comment: Thanks! You should probably paste the full code into this answer, though; links go bust every day.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way of doing this would be to implement `PartialEq`, roughly like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Rectangle<T, U> {
    x: T,
    y: U,
}

impl<T, U, X, Y> PartialEq<Rectangle<X, Y>> for Rectangle<T, U>
where
    T: PartialEq<X> + PartialEq<Y>,
    U: PartialEq<X> + PartialEq<Y>,
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &Rectangle<X, Y>) -> bool {
        self.x == other.x && self.y == other.y || 
            self.x == other.y && self.y == other.x
    }
}
```

Unfortunately for your specific case, integers and floating points cannot be compared for equality:

```
fn main() {
    let first = Rectangle { x: 3.2, y: 1 };
    let second = Rectangle { x: 1, y: 3.2 };
    let third = Rectangle { x: 3, y: 1 };

    assert_eq!(first, first);
    assert_eq!(first, second);
    assert_eq!(second, first);

    assert_ne!(first, third);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `{float}: std::cmp::PartialEq<{integer}>` is not satisfied

error[E0277]: the trait bound `{integer}: std::cmp::PartialEq<{float}>` is not satisfied
```

Instead, you'd need to define your own trait that defines "equality" and then implement it as being able to cross from floating point to integer.